# .net core targetting framework outputting to dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

If I build a default .net core project and run "dotnet publish" the web.config output has the library set to TestProject1.dll

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\TestProject1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

If I build a .net core project which targets the full framework and run "dotnet publish" the web.config output has the library set to TestProject1.exe

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\TestProject1.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

My hosting provider is blocking the .exe

Is there anyway to output to a .dll when building .net core to full framework?

I have tried various things with no success - such as changing the project type to Class Library.  But then on the publish phase the .runtime file was omitted.

Thanks

Comment: Say that you did manage to achieve this. How would you run the dll? Presumably you would need to use `dotnet.exe` which would most likely require a .net core install and therefore obviate the need for a self-contained app (.exe) in the first place?

Comment: When the project is built targetting core the webconfig is as follows
<aspNetCore processPath=".\TestApplication2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />

When it is built targetting framework
<aspNetCore processPath=".\TestApplication2.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />


So I am trying to build it using framework but output exactly how it would do if it was targetting aspnetcore 

Its weird why its different

Comment: I think it is worth reviewing [.NET Core application deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/), specifically the first two bullet points. Essentially FDD depends on `dotnet.exe`. SCD will include a .exe which acts as a host (same role as `dotnet.exe`). Your requirement does not appear to be covered by either of these.

Comment: If you somehow manage to create a self-contained dll, there will be no way of running it. To resolve your problem, I think you will either need to get your hosting provider to install the .net core framework on the web server (so you can deploy a FDD) or ask them not to block the .exe (so you can deploy a SCD).

Comment: Ok I will review the link you have sent thanks.  Essentially my issue is I wanted to make use of the new API in aspnetcore but still reference some older libraries I have which are full framework.  I believe I cannot do this unless I target full framework in the API project.